# OCaml regex: specify a number of occurrences

Tags: regex, ocaml

In OCaml, how can I specify a number of occurrences for a pattern in regex? I went through the Str module and cannot find an equivalent for the `{n}` quantifier.

For example, if I want to specify a "Year" pattern, i.e. exactly 4 digits, is there any way other than doing `"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"`?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems that there are no other way, according to this: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/libref/Str.html . The syntax looks awfully similar to ERE.

Comment: If you really need advanced features of regex: http://pcre-ocaml.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm not sure if it supports this particular feature, but ocaml-re is worth checkout. https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re

Answer (score 1):

Extending rgrinberg comment, ocaml-re (https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re) supports Perl, PCRE and Emacs mode, which support the {m,n} quantifier.

A link to a test showing that it supports it (using the perl mode): https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml-re/blob/master/lib_test/test_perl.ml#L80 .